# Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' and Module parse failed: Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, babel-loader

i am do a project, but this errors appears to me, i tried to solve my problem based on post that found in stackoverflow, but my problem doesn't solved.

errors:

```
  ./node_modules/ml-matrix/src/symmetricMatrix.js 7:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (7:2)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| export class SymmetricMatrix extends AbstractMatrix {
|   /** @type {Matrix} */
>   #matrix;
|   get size() {
|     return this.#matrix.size;
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
handleErrors @ webpackHotDevClient.js:174
push../node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js.connection.onmessage @ webpackHotDevClient.js:213
Show 3 more frames
Show less
index.js:1 ./node_modules/ml-matrix/src/matrix.js 1440:6
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1440:6)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|    * @type {Float64Array[]}
|    */
>   data;
| 
|   /**
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "virtualFairs",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/charts": "^1.4.2",
    "@ant-design/colors": "^6.0.0",
    "@ant-design/compatible": "^1.1.2",
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.6.2",
    "@ant-design/plots": "^1.1.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.8",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.8",
    "@craco/craco": "^6.4.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "ant-design": "^1.0.0",
    "antd": "^4.16.9",
    "antd-img-crop": "^3.16.0",
    "array-move": "^3.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.19.0",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.9.1",
    "craco-less": "^1.18.0",
    "depcheck": "^1.4.3",
    "firebase": "^8.8.0",
    "formik-antd": "^2.0.4",
    "gsap": "^3.7.1",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "prism-react-renderer": "^1.2.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "rc-queue-anim": "^1.8.5",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-auth-code-input": "^3.2.1",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.33.5",
    "react-bottom-scroll-listener": "^5.0.0",
    "react-code-input": "^3.10.1",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-content-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
    "react-csv": "^2.2.2",
    "react-dnd": "^14.0.4",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^14.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.3.4",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-highlight-words": "^0.18.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.12.0",
    "react-image-timeline": "^3.2.13",
    "react-images": "^1.2.0-beta.7",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^6.1.0",
    "react-intl": "^5.20.6",
    "react-notifications-component": "^3.1.0",
    "react-player": "^2.14.1",
    "react-query": "^3.39.1",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.5",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-render-html": "^0.6.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-share": "^4.4.0",
    "react-simple-maps": "^2.3.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^2.0.0",
    "react-svg-piechart": "^2.4.2",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "react-tooltip": "^4.2.21",
    "react-trello": "^2.2.11",
    "react-window": "^1.8.6",
    "recharts": "^2.0.10",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reqwest": "^2.0.5",
    "simplebar-react": "^2.3.6",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.3",
    "use-url-search-params": "^2.3.13",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.+(js|jsx)\"",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix \"src/**/*.+(js|jsx)\"",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.+(js|jsx)\"",
    "precommit": "lint-staged"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all",
      "not ie 11",
      "not chrome < 51",
      "not safari < 10",
      "not android < 51"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.18.2",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^13.1.0",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.42",
    "@types/react": "17.0.39",
    "@types/react-csv": "^1.1.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.5",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/react-simple-maps": "^1.0.8",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.8",
    "@types/yup": "^0.29.14",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "commitlint-config-jira": "^1.5.1",
    "commitlint-plugin-jira-rules": "^1.5.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.1",
    "lint-staged": "^11.1.1",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1"
  }
}
```